# I need to popup actionsheet above tabbar in my present viewcontroller, but it should not overlap tabbar(i need to see tabbar clearly)

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uikit, uiactionsheet

I need to popup transperant actionsheet above tabbar in my present viewcontroller, but it should not overlap tabbar(i need to see tabbar clearly).

Comment: What do you actually want? A transparent actionsheet? Or should the tabbar move up? Or something else? Please formulate questions more clearly and accurate

Comment: actually i want the tabbar icon to be seen clearly as actionsheet appear ...... could u please help......i am stuck with this from past 2 days ..... yea transperent actionsheet would help....!!!

Comment: i am using actionsheet on tabbarcontroller .... hence it should show the tabbar icons ..... thanks ...

Comment: I have posted a solution to show a transparent actionsheet. Would you want the tabBar icons still be clickable?

Comment: yea ?... how can i do that ?..... thanks for ur last answer....

Comment: If you want the tabBar to be still clickable, that breaks the purpose of a UIActionSheet, because this is deisnged to force the user to take an action, so being able to navigate away from this seems wrong. If you just want a view popping up with a few button I think you should use a UIView and animations. If you need some code for that, let me know

Comment: it would be helpful if u post some code !....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a transparant background on a UIActionsheet you have to set the delegate and then you can do:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    [actionSheet.layer setContents:nil];
}
```

---

---

To create a custom UIView that animates in from the bottom you can do>

```
bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 250)];
bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
bottomView.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubview:bottomView];

UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
testButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 40);
testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[bottomView addSubview:testButton];

[self animateBottomViewIn];
```

And have the following methods:

```
-(void)animateBottomViewIn
{
    bottomView.hidden = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - bottomView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, bottomView.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) { }];
}

-(void)animateBottomViewOut
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, bottomView.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        bottomView.hidden = YES;
    }];
}
```